# How to deploy Tomcat server apps using an Apache2 server and with the same domain name ? On Ubuntu

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, domain-name, mod-jk

- Ubuntu version: 18.04.4
- Tomcat version: 8
- Apache2 version: 2.4.29

Hi everyone, in my company, we have developed a web repository for a university in Java. Obviously, this app is colocated in a tomcat server.

The principal website of the university is in an Apache2 server. With a domain name and ssl certificate installed.
But now the problem is to have the same domain name or a sub domain (from the apache2 server) for the tomcat app.

Like: https://www.my-domain-from-apache.com/myTomcatApp

I tried this solution from this youtube tutorial at the bottom:

[Virtual Host + Apache httpd server + Tomcat + mod_jk connector](https://youtu.be/Njx1V4ZW_g0)

But I don't have the same result. My page no appeared.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can host multiple domains/subdomains on single Apache server. You can even route single domain to multiple context eg : www.abc.com/one and www.abc.com/two.
When you say "My page not appeared", can you post errors? Also if you can post details about Apache configuration,it will be helpful.

Comment: You should include `apache` configuration as well as `workers.properties` as @saurabh14292 told you.